# Can't get the set value of varible in one function in other diff func in the same class php

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I am having a problem with this variable "admin_user_id".. i want to set the val of the var in one function and use that var value in other function here..
But problem is that it gives null. i think its bcz of diff reference of the class..

```
class ChangeRequestProcessController extends AppController{
static $admin_user_id;
public function ajax_list_of_change_request(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $params = array();
    $params[] = $this->Auth->user('id');
    //debug($params);
    $result =  $this->AppProcess->callProcedure('ListOfChangeRequestProcess', $params);
    //echo("here:"+$result);
    $admin_user_id=$params[0];
    //debug( $this->admin_user_id);
    echo json_encode($result);
}

 public function application_attachment_upload_with_title() {
    $this->autoRender = FALSE;

    $attachment_array[]=$this->admin_user_id;///p_admin_user_id
    //$attachment_array[]="name";///p_uploaded_by
    $attachment_array[]=$_POST['title'];///p_attachment_title
   // $attachment_array[] = $loged_on_id;
    //$attachment_array[] = $_FILES[0]['name'];
    //$attachment_array[] = $_POST['title'];
    debug($attachment_array);
    $result = $application->AttachmentTemp->callProcedure('ChangeRequestAttachmentFinalAddWithTitle', $attachment_array);///call procedure

    echo json_encode($result);///result
}
```

how to solve this problem in php so that the value persists(i think static var will solve it..but it also gives undefined var error inside function)???
Thanks in advance

Comment: just use `$_SESSION` for storing it. From what I can tell, those are two distinct calls to the controller. So you can't "share" anything between them.

Comment: how to use session to store variable..can u pls give me an example..

Comment: Thanks i have got it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(this doesn't fit the comment box, so here i go...)*

Assuming

```
// your code to get this...
$admin_user_id = $params[0];
```

You can store it in a session using this:

```
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['admin_user_id'] = $admin_user_id; // again, assuming this is the value!
```

To read it (in your second call/method), simply do:

```
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}
$admin_user_id = $_SESSION['admin_user_id'];
```

For more info, see the [php.net: sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Thnx...i have already solved it from your first comment...Again thanks.